# Change the order of the row in database

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table named user_account and I have a column named customized_sort(int) use random number, so I can order by it in desc way and asc way.
For example, there are 10 records in the table:

[image: user_account record]

I want to put 3rd user to 1st place. I only need to change the column customized_sort'number less than 1st people.  For example, I change 60 to a number between 0 and 10 to put the 3rd place entry to 1st place and I do not need to change any other record. But it can only change x times at most (x means 1st user customized_sort). How can I deal with it?

Comment: sorry didn't understand last line `it can only change x times at most(x means 1st user customized_sort)` , can you explain in detail?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And your text isn't easy to comprehend btw.

Comment: In your problem description - do not use images - use text instead ...

Comment: Use a transaction. Use contiguous integers (1-10) for sort position. Any drag drop update tutorial will be able to explain the steps inside the transaction

Comment: @AmitK everytime i change someone's place,i have to choose one number between  x and y(for example between 100 and 200),so if i try much enough,the sort_number  that  i can choose will be used up

Comment: @GhostCat i have tried use floating, but i am not sure if i change times much enough ,the float will More and more digits.and my image  is 2 columns in one table , i can query from the table order by customized_sort and I can change the order at will.

Comment: @Plirkee sorry,it was my fisrt time to use stackoverflow to ask question.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry man,can you explain it  in more detail , and I haven't used English for a long time since i  graduated from university,so  I am a little difficult to read what you said.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to re-assign *customized_sort* for the users in-between - in this case *user1*, *user2* and *user3*.

Otherwise, you can update all records once you have run out of numbers. So the process happens only once in a while.

Or you can also use a floating-point type instead of an *int*. So you can always use decimals once you have used all integers.

Comment: thx,and i think maybe i can make  a schedule job to update all record everyday ,but i am afraid that i  update all records  may cause new problems

Comment: tbh your solution seems very complicated and heavy in resources compared to simply maintaining successive integers (1-10) and updating it every time sort is changing.